# Is accessing a 2D array as a flat array well-defined?

Tags: c

I know the internal representation of a multi-dimensional array is the same as the "flattened" array, but I'm looking here for an answer *if* (and if yes, *how* and *where*) the C standard allows me to do the following. Maybe I missed something, but I couldn't find any paragraph telling me that e.g. `int []` and `int [][]` are *compatible types*.

The concrete background: I did my own "toy" implementation of the [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)) game, and I have the following in my game state structure representing the board:

```
struct context
{
    // [...]
    int board[5][5];
    // [...]
};
```

This is a 2D array of "boolean integers" indicating whether a position is lit or not. As the game is won when all positions are unlit, I do the following to check this:

```
// parameter is `struct context *ctx`

for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
{
    if (((int *)ctx->board)[i])
    {
        won = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, this code works, but is it actually *well-defined* or should I use two nested loops iterating over both dimensions of `ctx->board`?

Comment: XY problem. The actual question is: why would one want to do this? Leave optimisations to the compiler! Too bad you don't post a [mcve] with all **relevant** code. But it is very likely you violate the effective type rule and invoke undefined behaviour. As a sidenote: using magic numbers is error prone and bad coding style.

Comment: All relevant code is here. And indeed, the answers to the linked duplicate are helpful, for some reason, I didn't find this question with my searches.